# Will a Serial DispatchQueue wait if a task spawns a different thread

Tags: ios, dispatch-queue

Serial dispatch queues will execute their tasks one at a time.  But what if I have task1 and task2 in the queue.  task1 one starts execution and calls a function with a completion block (which I assume will use a different thread to execute).  At this point, I believe task1 will exit, even though the completion block has not yet been called.  Is it a possibility that task2 will start executing before the completion block from task 1 is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the normal case, that's exactly what will happen.

If you want to wait for something to complete before continuing, research [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup).